# onActivityResult is not getting called

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, onkeydown

When I return from the child activity the onActivityResult is not called in the mainActivity. I am using finish() in the child activity.  Could you please let me know the reason ?

Thanks in Advance.

### MainActivity

```
private void goToHomePage() { 
    if(connected){
        basket.putString(key, "dummy");
        Intent i = new Intent(Splash.this,HomePage.class);
        i.putExtras(basket);
        startActivityForResult(i,0);  
    }else{
        alert(); 
    } 
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); 
    basket = data.getExtras();  
    Log.i("Splash","on activity result...");
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
        switch(requestCode){ 
        case 0:

            wifi.disConnect();
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

### Child Activity

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
        Log.i("HomePage","onKeyDown");
        sendBack("close"); 
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

public void sendBack(String command) { 
    Intent sendBack = new Intent(); 
    Bundle basket1 =new Bundle();
    basket1.putString("command", command);  
    sendBack.putExtras(basket1);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, sendBack);
    finish();   
}
```

Comment: add your child Activities manifest declaration.

Comment: <activity
            android:name=".HomePage"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.HOMPAG" /> 
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: it looks good , what about first activity too?

Comment: Did you properly debugged and make sure that your code in the onKeyDown is getting reached???

Comment: so are you sure, you are returning by back button only? or nything else is finishing activity, though still onAR should gets call with null result.

Comment: First Activity is the main Launcher Activity. It is declared in Manifest file. I checked the log. Control reaches the onKeyDown.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have

```
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

in your `onActivityResult`? I guess this is not required and that the control is getting to this statement and getting out of the method before your logic. Like in other comments, have you checked out debugging step by step if control reaches this statement?

Comment: Following is my log to say that the code reaches Finish() 
02-03 14:02:15.098: I/HomePage(31045): onKeyDown

02-03 14:02:15.098: I/HomePage(31045): just before finish

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to pass something to the main activity when the user presses the back key? In that case, try this:

1. In child activity, remove `onKeyDown()`.
2. In child activity, add this:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onBackPressed()
   {
       String command = "close";

       Intent sendBack = new Intent(); 
       Bundle basket1 =new Bundle();
       basket1.putString("command", command);  
       sendBack.putExtras(basket1);
       setResult(RESULT_OK, sendBack);
       finish(); 
       // Do not call super.onBackPressed() so as to ignore the default implementation.
   }
   ```

Comment: onBackPressed is getting called in child Activity. But not the onActivityResult in MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

It is my blunder, I have given  finish() in onPause of mainActivity. That closes the activity when it moves to child activity. Thanks again !